# adding new row in buttom of datagrid by editing cell one by one

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

try to add new row at my datagrid "sgv1" , the content of the datagrid is bound to table "TOR" .. problem is when i try to put value to first cell and leave it , i get nullexception reference because of the other cells. 
well that's right ,so how to deal with other cells .. how to pervent checking other cells untill i come to it and give it the value .. or any another solutions , any suggutions guys..

i have tried with event CellValidating to check cells , as mentioned above i get null refernece ..

```
private void Sgv1_CellValidating(object sender,DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
   {         
        try
             { 
                    DialogResult result;

                    switch (currentTable)
                    {
                        // name of table 
                        case "TOR":

                            if (sgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value== null)
                            {
                                result = MessageBox.Show("feld is empty , please enter a value", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                                {                      
                                    e.Cancel = false;

                                }

                            }
                            if (sgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FormattedValue == null)
                            {
                                result = MessageBox.Show("feld is empty , please enter a value", "error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                                {
                                    e.Cancel = false;

                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                   return;
                                 }

                                      break;
                        // antoher table
                        case "Puffer":
                            //  check it's Cells
                            break;

                        default: break;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: When a new row is first added there are some events you can use.  One is `DefaultValuesNeeded` which lets you provide safe defaults to start with, others are `NewRowNeeded`, `UserAddedRow` and there are even more in datatable

Comment: Are you sure your code is not throwing this exception? The second `if/else` condition looks odd… the statement `if (sgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].FormattedValue == null)` … if the cell is null you enter the `then` condition. However, if the cell is NOT NULL the `else` portion is throwing a null exception. This cannot be right.

Comment: you have right , both of if statment should be not Null , but this is not a problem , i should just use the right event , the CellValidating  event fired after rowleaver or CellEditEnd , so the validation  happens to late . hoever i used the event DefaultValuesNeeded  to set default value inside cells to empty string to avoid the null exception , was idea from Nyssa , thanks bro

Comment: I am not sure what the exact problem is. If a grids cell is `NULL` it is NOT going to throw an exception until you try to do something with the cell, like read it. Where/When exactly (line of code) are you getting the error and also what are you trying to validate in the cell?

Comment: Also, your comment… _”when i try to put value to first cell and leave it , i get nullexception reference because of the other cells”_ … how do you know that the exception is being thrown because of the other cells? From the grids perspective the null cells will NOT throw this exception.

Comment: If the goal is to “validate” the data the user inputs into each cell in a row in a grid AND make sure ALL cells have been filled with valid data, I recommend you make a small input form. If you `ShowDialog` with the input form, validating the data in this form will be easier than trying to validate the data as the user types into the grid’s cells.

Comment: hey John thanks, i got your idea , it works now